# How can I do to keep the value of a variable after a do while loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been coding a program to simulate a roulette of a casino, thing is that every time I try to repeat the game after is finished I want the game to keep going and the money to be the same, so if you have lost money you start with that certain money, here is the code (It's in Spanish but I think it's pretty clear):

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int num, pri, randum, num2, op, num3 = 10000, col = randum, rep, clear;
int main() {
    do {
        int num4 = op;
        cout << "Escoja la opción de la que apostar.\n";
        cout << "1 - Apostar a un número. \n2 - Apostar a un color \n";
        cout << "Elija opción: ";
        cin >> pri;
        cout << " \n";
        cout << " \n";

        switch (pri) {
        case 1: {
            srand(time(0));
            randum = rand() % 37 + 1; //si poner 37 + 1 te va cojer números hasta el 37 no?
            if (num4 != 10000) {
                cout << "Su saldo actual es " << num3 << " €\n";
            } else {
                cout << "Su saldo actual es 10000 €\n";
            }
            cout << "Ha elegido apostar a un número\n";
            cout << "Introduzca el dinero que quiere apostar -->\n";
            cin >> num;
            cout << "Ahora introduzca el número que desee entre el 0 y 36 -->\n";
            cin >> num2;

            if (num2 == randum) {
                op = num3 + num;
                cout << "\n¡Enhorabuena! Has ganado! Ahora tienes " << op << " €\n";
            } else {
                op = num3 - num;
                cout << "\nLo sentimos... Has perdido la apuesta, ahora tienes " << op << " €\n";
                cout << "¿Quieres volver a jugar?\n- Sí -> 1\n- No -> 2\n";
                cin >> clear;
                if (clear == 1) {} else if (clear == 2) {
                    cout << "Bien, suerte en la próxima tirada.\n\n";
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            if (num3 == 10000) {
                cout << "Su saldo actual es 10000 €\n";

            } else {
                cout << "Su saldo actual es " << num3 << " €\n";
            }
            cout << "Ha elegido apostar a un color\n";
            cout << "Introduzca el dinero que quiere apostar -->\n";
            cin >> num;
            srand(time(0));
            randum = rand() % 2 + 1;
            cout << "Ahora escoja rojo (1) o negro (2) -->\n";
            cin >> col;
            if (col == randum) {
                op = num3 + num;
                cout << "\n¡Enhorabuena! Has ganado! Ahora tienes " << op << " €";
            } else {
                op = num3 - num;
                cout << "\nLo sentimos... Has perdido la apuesta, ahora tienes " << op << " €";

            }
            cout << "¿Quieres volver a jugar?\n- Sí -> 1\n- No -> 2\n";
            cin >> clear;

            if (clear == 1) {} else if (clear == 2) {
                cout << "Bien, suerte en la próxima tirada.\n\n";
            }
        }
        }
    } while (clear == 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but move those calls to `srand` at the beginning of `main`. It should only be called once, at the start of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it should be pretty easy to do that.

Initialize the starting amount outside the loop before the betting begins.

At the end of the loop, ask if user wants to bet more.

Would that work for you? Or do you need it to be initialized when you start the code itself? You could use static

I am just changing a few things from your code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int money = 10000, bet_amount = 0, clear, pri;
    cout << "Su saldo inicial es " << money << " €\n";

    do
    {
        cout << "Escoja la opción de la que apostar.\n";
        cout << "1 - Apostar a un número. \n2 - Apostar a un color \n";
        cout << "Elija opción: ";
        cin >> pri;
        cout << " \n";
        cout << " \n";

        cout << "Introduzca el dinero que quiere apostar -->\n";
        cin >> bet_amount;

        switch (pri)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            int number_chosen = -1, randum;
            cout << "Ahora introduzca el número que desee entre el 0 y 36 -->\n";
            cin >> number_chosen;

            srand(time(0));
            randum = rand() % 37; // This will give result in the range 0 - 36

            if (randum == number_chosen)
            {
                money += bet_amount;
                cout << "\n¡Enhorabuena! Has ganado! Ahora tienes " << money << " €\n";
            }
            else
            {
                money -= bet_amount;
                cout << "\nLo sentimos... Has perdido la apuesta, ahora tienes " << money << " €\n";
            }

            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            int color = 0, randcol;
            cout << "Ahora escoja rojo (1) o negro (2) -->\n";
            cin >> color;
            srand(time(0));
            randcol = rand() % 2 + 1;
            if (randcol == color)
            {
                money += bet_amount;
                cout << "\n¡Enhorabuena! Has ganado! Ahora tienes " << money << " €\n";
            }
            else
            {
                money -= bet_amount;
                cout << "\nLo sentimos... Has perdido la apuesta, ahora tienes " << money << " €\n";
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
        }
        cout << "¿Quieres volver a jugar?\n- Sí -> 1\n- No -> 2\n";
        cin >> clear;
        if (clear == 2)
        {
            cout << "Bien, suerte en la próxima tirada.\n\n";
        }

    } while (clear == 1);

    cout << "Tu saldo final es " << money << " €\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It took me a while to figure out the code because I had to use google translate

Comment: Yes I need it before the loop, so you start with 10000$ and when you finish you have a certain amount of money and repeat the game, I have never used the loop function, could you show me the code done? I'm really lost, thanks.

Comment: Check the answer now @zona1616

Comment: Yes, I just checked it and it works perfectly, thank you so much !! I think I understand it now

Comment: cool. happy it worked for you. Please close the thread and mark it as the answer? Also please take note of using more relevant variable names so that reading code is easier. All the best

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store the money into a file 
Like this :

```
 #include <fstream>
    
 ofstream myfile ("money.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    myfile << "put the money in the bag here";
    myfile.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

And whenever you want to read the value 
Use this:

```
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("money.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
      getline (myfile,line);
      cout << line << '\n';
      myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

Comment: How can I include this in my code, do I have to make a different file or something?

Comment: The file will save the value for ever even if user closes the terminal . But of course the user can open it with block-note and add write 1 000 000 000 and become a billionaire . So you need to check that before reading the file in multiple ways.

Comment: But do I have to copy paste those things you sent me into my code or do I have to make it in another? Or maybe pasting that on the .txt file, I don't really get it sorry.

Comment: 1- #include <fstream> on the top . 2- create a function called storeNewMoney( amount ) and another one that returns the amount 3- when ever you want update or read how much the user has, call one of those functions

Comment: I'm sorry I can't find a way to make it work, I just started learning C++, here is what i understood to do:

Comment: Well, I don't have enough space to show it